# How to know if the response is from the CDN and not the origin?

Tags: http, firewalls, webserver, cdn

I am doing some bug hunting. I inserted a malicious payload into a request. But I am not sure if the response is from CloudFlare or the origin. Are there special headers which help me to distinguish the origin from the CDN? I always see the HTTP header `Server: CloudFlare` even if the response came from the origin. Why don't I see `Server: Nginx`?

Comment: I edited your question to change "firewall" to "CDN", because that's what CloudFlare is. Please look up what CloudFlare actually does. They have several diagrams on their site to explain. CloudFlare *is* the server.

Comment: Alright. Thank you for editing. I will take a look at it

Comment: @schroeder, A minor and respectful disagreement with you on this.  Cloudflare offers multiple services.  Among them is a Content Delivery Network (CDN) service (advertised at https://www.cloudflare.com/cdn), and another among them is a Web Application Firewall (WAF) service (advertised at https://www.cloudflare.com/waf).  I believe the OP's question is in regard to Cloudflare's WAF service.  Just my $0.02.

Comment: @mti2935 yep - I am aware. But if the response says `Server: CloudFlare` ...

Comment: @schroeder Yes, `Server: CloudFlare` is normally seen in the response headers for sites protected by Cloudflare's WAF.

Comment: @mti2935 I know what you are saying, and we are in agreement, I think. But CloudFlare's WAF is not a standard WAF. I think it goes far beyond a WAF and into "proxy" territory. And when the original post talked about merely the phrase "firewall", I wanted to shift the OP towards understanding what CloudFlare is doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how you're accessing the origin directly unless you're accessing the origin by using its IP. Once you point your domain name at Cloudflare, all requests go through Cloudflare.

Assuming you're accessing the domain name, the content itself did come from your origin even if Cloudflare is currently returning a cached response. You can see if it's a cached response based 'cf-cache-status' header (hit = Cloudflare cache, miss = Cloudflare had to make a request to your origin because it didn't have anything in cache).

You can also turn on Development Mode so Cloudflare bypasses cache.

> Temporarily bypass our cache. See changes to your origin server in realtime.

Cheers.